# page is still reloading the content even after data-dom-cache is true

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a following page in `jquery mobile`

**page A**

```
<div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true">

</div>
```

from page A i am moving to **page B** using `$mobile.changePage("b.html");` and from 
**page B's** back button i am going page to **page A** but the content of page A is getting reloaded even if i have set `data-dom-cache true`.

***note: when i press device's back button its working fine***

**Page B**

```
<div data-role="page">

    <a href="#" id="backBtn" >back</a>

 </div>

$("#backBtn").on('click',function(){

            $.mobile.changePage("A.html",{reloadPage:'false'});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aaah .. all i got to add the `data-rel=back` in `<a href="#" id="backBtn" >back</a>`

so the ans is

```
<a href="#" id="backBtn" data-rel="back">back</a>
```